# Where should I put system-wide scripts in *nix system?

Tags: linux, script

Can someone tell me of a sensible fairly standard place to put scripts that a number of users will need on an Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, your tags include the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) so that should give you some guidance. I would recommend `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I had a look there and couldn't find anything useful. Through quick manual inspection of `/usr/bin` I couldn't find any examples that weren't binary or symlinks, which made me think that maybe it wasn't normal to put scripts themselves in `bin` directories. But if you recommend it that's enough for me!

Comment: @Andy: There's a lot of stuff in `/usr/bin`. All that matters is that they should be (usefully) executable; it doesn't matter whether they're implemented as scripts or binaries. If you're curious, you can run `file /usr/bin/*` to see what kinds of files you have in `/usr/bin` on your machine.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, that makes sense. And I'd never heard of `file` so thanks again for that!

Answer (score 1):

I never put scripts that I write in /usr/bin.  Either /usr/local/bin or, preferrably, /opt/local/bin.  Virtually nothing's going to collide with or stomp on scripts in the latter.